# Search results security trimming for users, how it works?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search, content-search-web-part

I understand that during the indexing process (in context of lists/libraries) there are some library and item level ACL's generated, containing the users and groups that have access to the specified objects (items/documents).

However, in case new users and groups are added to the specified library that has been already indexed, does it mean that those new users/groups are not taken into account (users doesn't have access yet) until the next crawl that will refresh these ACLs ?

PS: Unfortunately I don't have a DEV environment to test this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, SharePoint will perform a crawl of the item when ACLs are adjusted to add or remove the visibility of that object from an end user.

Because of continuous crawls in SharePoint, this typically happens quickly, often in just a couple of minutes at the most.